# Eclipse+Derby - Program runs outside; Classpath+Eclipse conflict?

Tags: java, eclipse, derby, classnotfoundexception

When running the SimpleApp example from the Apache Derby packet by command line (java SimpleApp) it works flawless, so the classpath must be set correctly.
But when running inside Eclipse the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" error occurrs.

Could it be that eclipse somehow doesn't take the current classpath into account?

(Running on Win7x64, JRE+JDK7.25, Derby 10.10.1.1, CLASSPATH=C:\Users\User\Desktop\eclipse\workspace\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin\lib\der
by.jar;C:\Users\User\Desktop\eclipse\workspace\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin\lib\derbyt
ools.jar;.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse takes no notice of the CLASSPATH when running programs. You need to add the derby jars to the Libraries in Properties / Java Build Path for the project.